# Sql Server Ce 3.5 Check Constraints

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce, check-constraints

Does Sql Server ce Suports Check Constraints?
I wanted to do something like
"ALTER TABLE  WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT id_range_check CHECK ( BETWEEN  and )

and this will give an error on 'WITH'

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server Compact does not support CHECK constraint http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174123(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that CHECK CONSTAINT is not supported by SQL CE 3.5. The following code works (I originally had WITH CHECK but that failed):

```
ALTER TABLE [SiteUser] ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_SiteUser_Site] FOREIGN KEY([SiteId])
REFERENCES [Site] ([SiteId])
```

The following execution also fails.. so now it seems I can create the foreign key but can't enforce it.. what's the point then!?

```
ALTER TABLE [SiteUser] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_SiteUser_Site]
```

Answer (score 0):

"alter table [table_name] check constraint [constraint_name]" is a constraint validation statement, not a check constraint.

Answer (score -1):

Check constraints are supported, but the "`WITH NOCHECK`" option is not. Try removing that.

Answer (score -1):

I believe only simple constraints are supported your example above include a BETWEEN that would not be supported.